# query using subquery and joins optimization

Tags: mysql, join, subquery

I'm somehow not contented with my query statement and am wondering if there are other better way to do this:

```
SELECT product.product, 
 COALESCE((SELECT SUM(qty) FROM stocktrxn 
 INNER JOIN stock on stock.tra_no = stocktrxn.tra_no 
 WHERE product_no = s1.product_no and stock.is_out = false) - 
 (SELECT SUM(qty) FROM stocktrxn 
 INNER JOIN stock on stock.tra_no = stocktrxn.tra_no 
 WHERE product_no = s1.product_no and stock.is_out = true), 0)
 as qty
FROM stocktrxn s1
RIGHT JOIN product on product.id = s1.product_no
GROUP BY product ASC;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just want conditional aggregation.  Something like this:

```
SELECT p.product,
       (SUM(CASE WHEN s.is_out = false THEN qty ELSE 0 END) -
        SUM(CASE WHEN s.is_out = true THEN qty ELSE 0 END) -
       ) as qty
FROM product LEFT JOIN
     stocktrxn st
     ON p.id = st.product_no LEFT JOIN
     stock s
     ON s.tra_no = st.tra_n
GROUP BY p.product ASC;
```